# Converting Object to Map using Generics

Tags: javascript, typescript

## Problem

I am loading things from the `localStorage` and this has to be saved as json, so it needs to have a simple `Object` structure to be possible to `JSON.parse()`.

However, som methods do not accept `<any>` as parameter, because they want a concrete `class` or `interface`, but i want to send my object as parameter, so i have to convert it to a `Map` in order to have the same structure, but seen as it has a type, it is now accepted as parameter.

My problem lies within the conversion from `Object` to `Map`

## Solution

```
public static convertObjectToMap<V>(obj: any, classOfV): Map<string, V> {
    let objectMap = new Map<string, V>();
    if (obj !== undefined && obj !== null) {
      for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const initObject = new classOfV(obj[key]);
          objectMap.set(key, initObject);
        }
      }
    }
    return objectMap;
  }
```

I take an `obj` and the `class` which all values are going to be in the same type.

## Example of usage

```
//This is purely for the example
const fibonacciObject:any = {"0": 1, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 5};

const fibonacciMap:Map<string, Number> = convertObjectToMap<Number>(fibonacciObject, Number);

fibonacciMap.get("0"); //1
fibonacciMap.get("4"); //5
```

## Question

Is there a better way to do this conversion, i know about `new () => V`, but since i need it for each key, then it is not really feasible.

Also what Type would `class` of `V` be, i keep getting type errors when i try to give it a Type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points first.

1. Avoid `any` like the plague. You can nearly always figure out a better type. When dealing with a JSON serialized data, I like to have a function similar to this to get rid of any as soon as possible:

   ```ts
   function verify<T>(obj: any, fallback: T, isT: (obj: any) => obj is T): T {
     return isT(obj) ? obj : fallback;
   }
   ```
2. `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` are a better fit for looping through an object if you are going to check `hasOwnProperty`. I prefer `Object.entries` when possible, if you have the browser support.
3. Choose `const` or `let`, don't mix them without good reason. `const` can result in better type inference so I prefer to use it when possible.

Here is how I would implement this function.

```ts
function convertObjectToMap<In, Out>(
  obj: { [K: string]: In } | undefined | null,
  classOfIn: new (v: In) => Out
): Map<string, Out> {
  const result = new Map<string, Out>();

  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj || {})) {
    result.set(key, new classOfIn(val));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: What would the generic parameters for `In` and `Out` be, and isn't `classOfIn(obj[key])` supposed to be `classOfIn(val)`

Comment: Fixed `classOfIn`, In your example case it would be `<number, Number>`, but it can be left off since Typescript can infer the type from the `classOfIn` parameter.

Comment: Most of the time In and Out would be the same type though right?

Comment: That greatly depends on how you use the function, if you are just using strings and numbers, yes. However this could work with more complex classes.

Comment: My constructor for the classes for this looks like this `constructor({name, age}){  //Unpacked can be used right away }` I would probably not use it for Number, but it was the simplest example i could make up

Comment: I reduced it to only `<Out>`. If i ever happen to run into the In Out problem then i'll change it, it will be a create way to realize when the generic type is too restrictive, also thanks for showing me the index types, i never bothered to read more into it, but it's pretty simple